# Javascript: split a string according to two criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to count the number of sentences in a paragraph. In the paragraph, all sentences end with either ''.'' or ''!''.

My idea is to first split the paragraph into strings whenever there's a ''.'' or ''!'' and then count the number of splitted strings.

I have tried

```
.split('.' || '!')
```

but that does not work. It only splits strings whenever there is a ''.''

May I know how to deal with this?

Comment: take a look at regex

Comment: `'.' || '!'` will always yield `'.'` as `'.'` is a truthy value. Besides this, if you're sure that the string passed will contain valid sentences, you can simply count the number of `.` and `!` to find out the number of sentences.

Comment: Use a regexp, that will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a Regexp, it's pretty simple ;)

```js
const example = 'Hello! You should probably use a regexp. Nice isn\'t it?';
console.log(example.split(/[.!]/));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a regex for this.
The following should work:

```
.split(/\.|!/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/\.|!/` in `split()` as `str.split(/\.|!/)` :

```js
var str = 'some.string';
console.log(str.split(/\.|!/));

str = 'some.string!name';
console.log(str.split(/\.|!/));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sampleString = 'I am handsome. Are you sure?! Just kidding. Thank you.';
const result = sampleString.split(/\.|!/)
console.log(result);

// to remove elements that has no value you can do
const noEmptyElements = result.filter(str => str);
console.log(noEmptyElements);
```

Comment: I notice that there's an empty string after ''Thank you''. May I know why? @sorxrob

Comment: Because of the spaces after the separators

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will give you an exact count of sentences in the paragraph.

```
function count(string,char) {
 var re = new RegExp(char,"gi");
 return string.match(re).length;
}


function myFunction() {

 var str = 'but that! does! not work. It only splits strings whenever there is a. ';
console.log(count(str,'[.?!]'));
}
```